# NodeJS Socket.io private message code not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, mongoose, chat

I am trying to develop a chat app, with the ability to send private messages. I have been stuck for over a week now. The private message part is not working right.

Here is my code for when a user want to send a private message: 
It basically checks if the user is online, and if get the socket of that user from the user dict. and broadcast it to that user,and the user who send it himself.

```
socket.on('send message', function(data, callback){
var msg = data.trim();

var name = req.params.posteruname;

  if(name in users){
   users[name].emit('new message', {msg: msg, nick: socket.nickname});
   users[req.user.username].emit('new message', {msg: msg, nick: socket.nickname});
} 
else{
   callback('Error!  Enter a valid user.');
}


 });
```

Here is the client side code:

```
 socket.on('new message', function(data){
 if(data.nick == "{{reciever}}" || data.nick == "{{user.username}}") {
displayMsg(data);
}
  });
```

It basically checks again, if it is being broadcasted to either the receiver or the sender.

Here is the code for when a new user joins:

```
    socket.on('new user', function(data, callback){
       if (data in users){
          callback(false);
       } else{
      console.log(users);
      callback(true);
      socket.nickname = req.user.username;
      users[socket.nickname] = socket;
      updateNicknames();
      console.log(users);
    }
  });

  function updateNicknames(){
    io.sockets.emit('usernames', Object.keys(users));
  }
```

Every time i try to send a message, it doesn't display on the sender's screen and does so twice on the receiver's screen. And when a third user connects, sending a message will only broadcast on the third user's screen, even though its supposed to be between user1 and user2.

Answer (score 0):

Hi us this code server side:
var socketConnections={};

```
socket.on('userID',function(data)
{
   socket.userID=data.userID;
   socketConnections[socket.userID];

});
socket.on('sendMessage',function(data){

         socketConnection[data.receiverID].emit('message',{message:data.message,senderID:socket.userID});
 });
```

client side code

```
socket.emit('userID',{userID:'anyUniqueID'});

socket.emit('sendMessage',{message:'hi this murugan',receiverID:'uniqueReceiverID'});

socket.on('message',function(data){
//Private message     
console.log(data.message);
```

});

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work. I am just wondering, how is it any different than what I have?

Comment: I posted it. Check the question now.

Comment: client must be emit some uniqueid correct please add socket.emit('new user',{uniqueid}); in client side